# Скрипт для уменьшения цен на товары (тильда)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tilda

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть сайт на тильде, для примера кину сюда страницу https://zoopijon.ru/page37914024.html, нужно чтоб все цены на все товары отображались с учетом скидки (те уменьшенные на определенный процент), и в самом каталоге, и в поп-апе. Ума не приложу что с этим делать, очень надеюсь поможете с решением.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.